# What should a POST request in the Apache access log look like?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I'm having a difficult time with some incoming requests - they don't seem to be served properly for a particular equest. When I check the apache access log it looks like this:

```
[09/Nov/2011:23:43:00 +0000] "POST https://www.example.com/foursquare/push HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Does this indicate something is wrong? Other post requests for the same resource (say when I access it directly via a browser) look like this:

```
[09/Nov/2011:23:42:43 +0000] "POST /foursquare/push HTTP/1.1" 200 75
```

I don't know enough to understand the difference -- hoping someone could explain a bit.

Comment: The top example is going to a secure site (https) and is being (temporarily) redirected (302) somewhere else. This behaviour is likely a result of not having an SSL virtualhost setup (or setting it up to redirect) - in which case, the original page would not have received the data. In the other request, the 200 status indicates a successful request (and 75 is the response size in bytes). One option is to configure your SSL virtualhost to accept connections to that page.

Answer (score 2):

```
[09/Nov/2011:23:43:00 +0000] "POST https://www.example.com/foursquare/push HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

The main difference there, that I would look really closely at is the HTTP response code.  A response code of 302 is an HTTP redirect.

Comment: Not really sure how that's helpful. The first is a POST request which comes from a server I have no control of; the second from a web browser. Why would they be treated differently when requesting the same URL?

Comment: Given the information, only in the log file, you basically have no idea.  The difference is almost certainly something to do with the state.  Different data in the post request, different cookies, different http authentication.  If the server isn't https, then fire up tcpdump/wireshark.

Comment: @Zoredache i am having a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/55930602/815929.  I have logged request headers on the server side and the only difference i see in the requests is with the cookies. How to dig deeper?